# Rails 3: My view is not being rendered

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, rendering

I'm new to rails. I have my controller and view setup.

When I view my html source, my body is empty. I put a debugger in my controller and my view and it hits both so I know it's being executed. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I have also installed bootstrap.

Thank you in advance. 
see below.

```
class ListController < ApplicationController
  def recent
    @page_title = @head_title="Lists"
  end
end
```

recent.html.erb

```
    <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
</ul>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Myapp" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>

</html>
```

html source code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="7imEFVfD5bYIV7ZcK4181eCoz0pKxyyE2G+UFI46v5U=" name="csrf-token" />

  </head>

</html>
```

from the server logs

> Started GET "/list/recent" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri May 18 17:54:57 -0700 2012
>   Processing by ListController#recent as HTML
>     Rendered list/recent.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 16.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um, you don't have a `<body>` tag or any view contents in your application.html.erb file?  :-)

Try adding this just befor your `</html>`:

```
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

That `yield` with no argument will grab the content from the rendered view and spit it into your application layout.